# Limit a users access in vsftp to the home directory

Tags: linux, ftp, raspbian, vsftpd, home-directory

I have the following setup:

(1) raspberry pi 3 with Raspbian and vsftp.

The goal is to be able to connect to the ftp raspberry with clients such as WinSCP or Filezilla.

It is possible right now but the user is allowed to see other directories and download from everything. Only upload is limited to his home directory.

This is what I tried so far:

- creating a dedicated ftp user with

  adduser ftpuser --home /home/ftpuser/
- editing the config of vsftp in /etc/vsftp.conf [see here (justpaste.it)](https://jpst.it/QpjN)

So how do I go about this from here?

Comment: Straight from the configuration file `#chroot_local_user=YES`. Did you try to uncomment that line to see what happens?

Comment: @Seth unfortunately I believe no user was able to login after doing that. But I'll try it out again right now
Edit: error message from FileZilla:
Response: 500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
Error: Critical error: Could not connect to server

Comment: In that case ... make the root not writable or use `allow_writable_chroot`? Mind you [vsftp: why is allow_writeable_chroot=YES a bad idea?](http://serverfault.com/questions/743949/vsftp-why-is-allow-writeable-chroot-yes-a-bad-idea)